# Google Spreadsheeet (With App Script) on iPad

Tags: ipad, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with macros written using Google App Script. The macro is invoked with a click of button on the spreadsheet.

While this works fine on my Laptop (Windows), I don;t see the button on my iPad (iOs6).
And as the button is not visible, there is no way to invoke the macro. I am using Google Drive App for iPad to select and open the Google Spreadsheet on iPad.

Comment: You can add a menu item to execute the script, rather than using a button. Would you want to do this? in onOpen() you can add a menu option that can be used to execute your function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get scripts to work with phones and tablets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851641/how-to-get-scripts-to-work-with-phones-and-tablets)

Answer (score 4):

While I'm sure there are other issues at play, it's possible this functionality also runs afoul of Apple's "no execution of arbitrary code" policy for iOS apps. I imagine they would be fine skirting this by executing the script server-side (which I believe is how it is done with the web app, anyway) but I don't think they will ever be able to offer scripts in documents offline unless Apple changes their policy.

Answer (score 3):

Several years later... If the GAS application  is published as a google Web App, the URL for the app can be added as a link in the Google sheet and invoked that way, whether the sheet is accessed via PC-based web browser, or on Android or IOS via the Google Sheets app.

To create the link
=HYPERLINK("https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyy/exec","Generate Invoice")

Within the Web App doGet() can invoke a HTML UI if needed and that can interact with the Web App in the usual way (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

Its a bit clunky but it works.

Answer (score 1):

While the Google Drive app on iOS and Android has had some recent updates, the focus appears to have been on collaboration rather than automation. As you note, support for embedded graphics is not there yet (June 2013), nor is UI support (custom menus, Browser object, UiApp elements).

Comment: NP - sorry there isn't better news. As many answers say, you could raise an issue on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues).