# How to run a script which in the google spreadsheet from the Android Google Drive App?

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried the following:

1. **Create a menu item**
   -> the menu cannot be found in android google drive app.
2. **Draw a button and assign function**
   -> android google drive app cannot show the button.
3. **Add function to onOpen()**
   -> when I open spreadsheet from android google drive app, the function doesn't be executed.

So, how to do it?

Comment: I don't think you can run App script from Android devices...

Comment: @Vasim, are you sure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204975/google-spreadsheeet-with-app-script-on-ipad/17222844#17222844.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found to run scripts from within the Google Sheets app is to use the `onEdit()` trigger. You devise a code that will never be entered as real data. When you enter the code `onEdit()` can run the script function as if you ran it from the menu or Script Editor. It sounds hokey but it actually works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

FYI.
Now, with latest app update you can at least see drawings in Android Google Sheets App, but the "assigned script" (assigned from script editor in desktop version, that is) doesn't seem to fire.