# google speadsheet api onOpen does not work on mobile ios

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I tried working on the onOpen code and it works on google chrome on macbook but when I use it on google chrome on mobile ios the onOpen it doesnt call.

```
function onOpen() {
   Logger.log("OK")
}
```

Is there anyone api for mobile ios or other method to make onOpen works on mobile?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't activate? Use `console` instead of `Logger`, since Stackdriver will persist logs for at least a month.

Comment: Related: [Executing Google Apps Script Functions from Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33373826/1595451)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get scripts to work with phones and tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851641/how-to-get-scripts-to-work-with-phones-and-tablets)

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87361/27487 was very helpful for me.