# App Script not showing menu items using the Sheets app on iPad

Tags: ios, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've looked through several of the "possible duplicate" questions and didn't find exactly what I was looking for so I thought I'd ask.

I have an App Script that adds a menu item in order to perform a specific function.  The menu, of course, shows and works as expected on my desktop google sheets but does not show menu items at all on my iPad in the Sheets app.  I can try to run the sheet on the iPad in desktop mode but that is manual and clunky.

Are any of these options possible?

1. Some way to have the menu items show in the iPad sheets app?
2. Some way to detect if I'm running in the sheets app in which case, I can take a different action in my onOpen trigger?
3. Force the app to run in desktop mode always?

I'm thinking the answer is no to at least the first 2 of these but wanted to ask anyway.

Comment: As far I can tell iOS Sheets app has no such feature. You have to use a browser to get the custom menu. Moreover not every browser works fine in this respect. By my experience Firefox works surprisingly better than Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Ok thanks. That was my conclusion but thought it was worth asking the experts

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Yuri Khristich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14265469/yuri-khristich), this does not work on the regular mobile app. The workaround is to open the desktop version using a browser instead.

References:

- [Add a script trigger to Google Sheet that will work in Android mobile app](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/add-a-script-trigger-to-google-sheet-that-will-work-in-android-mobile-app/87361#87361)
- [How to get scripts to work with phones and tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851641/how-to-get-scripts-to-work-with-phones-and-tablets)
- [Executing Google Apps Script Functions from Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373826/executing-google-apps-script-functions-from-mobile-app)